# Uncaught TypeError: UICtrl.getDOMstrings is not a function

Tags: javascript, dom, closures

```
var budgetController = (function() {


})();

//UI CONTROLLER
var UIController = (function () {

    var DOMstrings = {
        //so i won't have to change '.add__type' for example everywhere in the code if i decide to modify my html
        inputType: '.add__type',
        inputDescription: '.add__description',
        inputValue: '.add__value',
        inputBtn: '.add__btn'

    };

    return {
      getInput: function(){
          return {
              type: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).value,//will be wither inc or exp
              description: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputDescription).value,
              value: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputValue).value
          };

      },
        getDomstrings: function() {
            //exposing the domstring object to the public
            return DOMstrings;
        }
    };

})();


//GLOBAL APP CONTROLLER
var controller = (function(budgetCtrl,UICtrl) {

    var DOM = UICtrl.getDOMstrings();

    var ctrlAddItem = function () {

        //1. get the field input data
        var input = UICtrl.getInput();
        console.log(input);

        //2.Add the item to the budget controller

        //3.Add the item to the UI

        //4. Calculate the budget

        //5. Display the budget on the UI


    }

    document.querySelector(DOM.inputBtn).addEventListener('click',ctrlAddItem);

    document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
        // enter has that key code(13)
        if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
            ctrlAddItem();
        }

    });

})(budgetController,UIController);
```

The exact error i'm getting in the console is :

```
app.js:39 Uncaught TypeError: UICtrl.getDOMstrings is not a function
    at app.js:39
    at app.js:68
(anonymous) @ app.js:39
(anonymous) @ app.js:68
```

Actively learning javascript and got stuck on that error that doesn't make sense as `.getDomstrings()` is a function defined above and public so should have access to it. And there is no need to add the html probably but in case there is kindly let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is a case-sensitive language you must use the exact same name of language keywords, function, variables etc when you use them.

so your function `getDomstrings` is not valid when called as `getDOMstrings`.

you must call the function as `getDomstrings` or change the function name to `getDOMstrings` then you can call as `getDOMstrings`.

so your following code:

`var DOM = UICtrl.getDOMstrings();`

should be:

`var DOM = UICtrl.getDomstrings();`